# Delete on mobile gives double prompts

Tags: bug, moderator-tools, mobile-web, vote-to-delete

When a <strike>moderator</strike> user clicks to delete a post on the mobile site, we are presented with two Javascript confirmation prompts; one asking "vote to delete this post?", and another asking "delete this post". The same thing happens on undelete.

<strike>It seems we are being presented with both the confirmation meant for regular users and mods (in that order).</strike>

Side details: Confirming the first one always (un)deletes, regardless of what is chosen on the second. Cancelling the first one results in an error if we confirm the second, or nothing at all (the expected behavior) if we also cancel the second.

Admittedly, extremely minor!

Comment: I think I saw this a while back and that it happens to everyone.

Comment: Hmm, let me try, but I indeed think I have the same on mobile as a non-mod.

Comment: @Bart You are correct; I found I've posted a duplicate!

Comment: @FDinoff Yup; marking this as a dupe...

Comment: This is so you can't claim you deleted it accidentally. ;)